# Can SqlCommand.Cancel() handle rollback while trasaction.commit is happening?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am not very familiar what SQL Server is undergoing cancelling current running job / rollingback the transactions committed so please bear with me (I have read articles and still not clear on this). I don't necessarily have to know all details happening in SQL Server but want to properly invoke requests to handle cancel properly (and whether rollback is done properly).

What I am trying to achieve here is cancelling the long running SQL operation.
I can think of couple different situations within `Using(SqlConnection)` bracket when the cancel request is invoked by user and I am still not certain after reading suggested answers in different threads if the proposed solutions handle below scenarios properly including rollback of transactions currently in `Commit()`.

1. While the code executes within `Using(SqlConnection)` block and still in process of multiple `ExecuteNonQuery()` or any other execute steps (i.e. `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`, etc.) but has not reached `SqlCommand.Transaction.Commit()` yet (probably rollback is not needed in SQL Server in my guess)
2. When the code finally reached `SqlCommand.Transaction.Commit()` and it is a long running commit and user wants to cancel in the middle of `Commit()` (probably rollback is needed in SQL Server. Does `SqlCommand.Cancel` actually work even at this point?)
3. When somehow there was an error in SQL Server and error has been returned and asking user if user wants to cancel this work (is this even necessary? I assume then `Command.Cancel()` should be in the exception handle block to cancel the transactions and rollback the error states). I am not certain what current state is in SQL Server and if rollback is required.

The sample code would be similar to this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel?view=netframework-4.7.2

The shown code below would be reflecting similar situations:

```
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    var Command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cts.Token.Register(() => 
                        {
                            Command.Cancel();
                            //Command.Transaction.Rollback(); 
                        });

                    Command.CommandText = some sql query;
                    Command.Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                    try
                    {
                        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //...  and May more transactions, long running job.
                        // User invokes cancel request (Scenario #1).

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                    }

                    // This Commit is expected to take long time.
                    // User invokes cancel request while stepped into this call and hasn't got out yet. (Scenario #2).
                    Command.Transaction.Commit();  
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Maybe rollback is necessary here if SqlCommand.Cancel is not availble at this point?
            // User invokes cancel request (Scenario #3).
        }

        private void UserRequestsCancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
```

Comment: "rollingback the transactions committed " - you can't rollback a committed transaction. That's sort of the point! You rollback an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: That's what's confusing me... what if the the commit() is not done yet and it is long running..your debug step entered Commit() and has not stepped out from this call. That is scenario #2 above.

Comment: If the cancel happens before the commit, the transaction is rolled back, otherwise, it's not. Whether the cancel will arrive before the commit, if they happen asynchronously, is a pure race issue that could be resolved either way. As a result, it's possible that a transaction has been committed at the database  while the client doesn't know if it is. It is not, however, possible that a client gets "OK, committed" from the database while the transaction *hasn't* been committed. (Barring things like delayed durability.)

Comment: Calling `Rollback` explicitly is generally not necessary, because it will be done by the `Dispose` invoked by the `using` if it has not been committed. This *may* cause an error if the server has already rolled back the transaction in response to an error (like the one triggered by cancelling). This can be handled by setting a flag when you invoke cancellation, and ignoring subsequent errors (like the scary sounding, but harmless, "a severe error has occurred on the current command").

Comment: Should I consider then, in above scenario #2, Cancel() is not possible? After reading comments that seems to be the case and Rollback wouldn't work either..

Comment: Why not use the async methods in `SqlCommand` like `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` and explicitly pass the token on calls that you would want to cancel? You can pass the cancellation token into these. Commit has no such overload so you will never cancel when calling Commit. That should take care of the issue.

Comment: That confirmed.. I was looking for such option during commit() and final answer seems to be it is not possible.  Thanks.